# Override InputDecorator Widget Functionality (internally called)

Tags: flutter, overriding

Ok. There's an InputDecorator Widget and an InputDecoration class. if you make a TextField you provide the class:

```
TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(...)...),
```

Now, if you follow the execution you'll see that internally, in the framework builds an InputDecorator in the TextField build function:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/553593741acdfb865ac9b870801ccc4ac457ef7f/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_field.dart#L1425

```
return InputDecorator(
            decoration: _getEffectiveDecoration(),
            baseStyle: widget.style,
            textAlign: widget.textAlign,
            textAlignVertical: widget.textAlignVertical,
            isHovering: _isHovering,
            isFocused: focusNode.hasFocus,
            isEmpty: controller.value.text.isEmpty,
            expands: widget.expands,
            child: child,
          );
```

Then the InputDecorator makes a fun decision about the gap between the content of the TextField and the label in its build function:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/553593741acdfb865ac9b870801ccc4ac457ef7f/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/input_decorator.dart#L2409

```
      // 4.0: the vertical gap between the inline elements and the floating label.
      floatingLabelHeight = (4.0 + 0.75 * labelStyle.fontSize!) * MediaQuery.textScaleFactorOf(context);
```

This results in a minimum gap imposed by the framework itself. I don't like that. Design on the left, what I'm able to create on the right:

[image: 4.0 gap minimum]

All I want to do is have control over that 4.0 number. specifically, I want to make it 0. But correct me if I'm wrong: I have to extend the InputDecorator State and widget, as well as the TextField State and Widget in order to do so, right?

Is there any other way to override the build function in the internally used InputDecorator Widget so I can change that hard coded number?

floatingLabelGap would be an easy thing to add to the InputDecorator class.